# I have a separate .json file, I need to iterate over the file or read through the file and do some stuff. How exactly do I do this in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, file

I have a folder with an html, css, json, and js file. The js file are a list of person's and what they do. I need to analyze the json file contents using javacript. I know that in C or C++ you can open the file for reading and analyze it, then close it. So, how do I do this in Javascript? And do I need to add the name of the JSON array in the .json file, or should i leave the contents as it is?

[JSON screenshot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctKi2.jpg)

Nothing online have worked thus far. Hopefully Stackoverflow can help.

Comment: you should provide more pieces of code. also the code you already tried

Comment: Stackoverflow works best when you ask tightly focused questions. It isn't clear if your problem is about reading the file (which depends on your JavaScript runtime (e.g. Node.js and Browsers have very different ways of doing that), or about parsing the JSON, or about iterating over the array. What's more, all of those things are *really common problems* so your question gives the impression that you've done no [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) at all. You should also read [ask] which has lots of good advice.

Comment: "And do I need to add the name of the JSON array in the .json file" – this doesn't really make sense. Arrays don't have names in JSON or JavaScript. Are you suggesting writing the JavaScript code for assigning data to a variable in the JSON file? JSON isn't JavaScript.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Let's assume you're using nodeJS, you can import the json file using `require` .

After you've imported the json file, you can access the object as it would be a JS object.

```js
const jsonFile = require("./pathtofile.json")

for(let obj in jsonFile) {
    console.log(obj)
}
```